# Difference between attribute and alternative in HTML images

Tags: html

Is their any difference between attribute and alt in html images. If any how do I display them. For-instance in this question
"Within the .mdc-card__primary-action DIV, create an IMAGE with an attribute of data-card-type and set its SRC to https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX1WX.png. This IMAGE will be used to display the credit card type, based on the series of numbers entered by the user" How should the image attribute "DATA-CARD-TYPE" be displayed.

I had done this but it is giving me an error 
`<div class="mdc-card__primary-action">
<img src="http://placehold.it/120x60.png?text=Card" alt="data-card-type"/>
</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alt` and `data-card-type` (and `src`) are all attributes.

```
<img 
    src="http://placehold.it/120x60.png?text=Card"
    alt="A text replacement for the image"
    data-card-type="some value">
```

`alt` and `data-card-type` are not alternatives for each other. They have different meanings.

[`alt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Attributes) is used to provide a textual replacement for the image (so that users who can't see the image — e.g. because their network is too unreliable, or they depend on a screen reader, or they are a search engine indexing bot — can understand what information the image conveys). The late Alan Flavell wrote [some excellent advice on writing alt text](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html).

[`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attributes have no standard meaning. They are provided so websites can embed custom data about elements in their HTML documents. This is most commonly used by the site's own JavaScript. Consequently, we have no way of knowing what the `data-card-type` attribute is for, we aren't privy to the context. (The name suggests it is not remotely related to alternative text though).